# .certSigningRequest is lost. what should I do?

Tags: ios, app-store, certificate

I've reinstalled OS after mysterious issue with keyboard and forgot to save .certSigningRequest file. the only file I have saved is certificates in .p12 file and have successfully set all this stuff back into my new login keychain. Now I am getting message 'valid signing identity not found'. I can't even run my app on my iPhone. What should I do now?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in this case just need to run the certificates procedure again. Request from KeyChain and then download them and install. This approach worked for me.

Comment: Go in to KeychainAccess app and request certificate from there. Instructions are given on the Apple Developer Program website.

Answer (score -1):

The .certSigningRequest is not the important one. You probably lost the private key.

Check this image.
If you can see the Key-Line in your keychain when you open your iPhone Developer/iPhone Distribution Certificate, then login to developer.apple.com/iOS re-download the provisioning file and all should be fine.
[image]

Comment: I have one really ancient backup since Leopard. There's no any apple certificates stored.

Comment: login to developer.apple.com/iOS re-download the provisioning file and all should be fine

Comment: Ok. and where do I need to set it now?

Comment: anyway it says 'valid signing identity not found'. just added it to organizer iPhone provisioning profiles.

Comment: xcode complains that my iPhone distribution certificate has no identity. there's really no key.

Comment: The certSigningRequest is an important one, as that is directly related to private key - changing a private key by generating another should require all that depends on the old one, to need to reconnect. (existing app would have to be recompiled for example), which should be unnecessary if you plug in the original CSR.